# tensorflow-1.0.1-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

I am using python 3.7 and after running the command:

```
python -m pip --upgrade tensorflow
```

it is showing me an error of:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem on Windows and at the same time did not have it on macOS. The solution was to install `Anaconda` or the image of tensorflow in `docker`.